# Detect if an image is transparent in GraphicsMagick

Tags: image, png, alpha, graphicsmagick

I am trying to check whether an image is actually transparent , not just check alpha channel.

To demonstrate, lets create an image `a.png` that has an alpha channel but is fully opaque, and an image `b.png` that is the same except for one translucent pixel:

`gm convert rose: PNG32:a.png`

`gm convert rose: -fill '#0008' -draw "matte 10,10 point" PNG32:b.png`

With ImageMagick we can easily check the trasparency with `%[opaque]`

```
$ identify -format '%[opaque]' a.png
true
$ identify -format '%[opaque]' b.png
false
```

What is the equivalent for graphicsmagick , `%A` only check if transparency is **supported** not that the image is actually transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

A slightly simpler method has since sprung to mind. Read the original answer below to understand what I am doing.

You can extract the alpha/opacity channel using `gm` and then you will not have to worry about multiple channels in the `-verbose` info output:

```
gm convert b.png -channel opacity -verbose info:-
```

**Sample Output**

```
gm convert a.png -channel opacity -verbose info:- 
a.png PNG 70x46+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 7.6Ki 0.000u 0m:0.000000s
Image: a.png
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Geometry: 70x46
  Class: DirectClass
  Type: grayscale
  Depth: 1 bits-per-pixel component
  Channel Depths:
    Gray:     1 bits
  Channel Statistics:
    Gray:
      Minimum:                     0.00 (0.0000)
      Maximum:                     0.00 (0.0000)
      Mean:                        0.00 (0.0000)
      Standard Deviation:          0.00 (0.0000)
  Filesize: 0
  Interlace: No
  Orientation: Unknown
  Background Color: white
  Border Color: £DFDFDF
  Matte Color: £BDBDBD
  Page geometry: 70x46+0+0
  Compose: Over
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: Zip
  Png:IHDR.color-type-orig: 6
  Png:IHDR.bit-depth-orig: 8
  Signature: d7e8478261a01c7f4c4f6bbb172976d1bd585c1b43195cdb65bafb008f71b5c6
  Tainted: True
a.png INFO 70x46+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 0.000u 0m:0.010000s
```

Now you can simply look for (`grep`), and count (`-c`) the lines that contain the word `"Maximum:"` followed by any digits other than zero. So you will get a zero or a one (`-m1`) as output:

```
gm convert b.png -channel opacity -verbose info:- 2>&1 | grep -c -m1 "Maximum:.*[1-9]"
```

**Original Answer**

Mmmm, **GraphicsMagick** is somewhat less developed than **ImageMagick** in many respects!

A couple of ideas come to mind. If you run:

```
gm identify -verbose a.png > a.txt
gm identify -verbose b.png > b.txt
```

and diff them, you will see the differences like this:

[image]

So, you could either look for `"Type: true color with transparency"`, or look at the `Channel Statistics->Opacity->Maximum` and check if it is greater than zero. That is somewhat hard to search for because the word `Opacity:` occurs twice but you can do it with `awk` like this:

```
gm identify -verbose a.png | awk '/Channel Statistics:/{f=1} (f==1)&&/Opacity:/{f=2} (f==2)&&/Maximum:/&&($2>0.00){print "Non-opaque pixel found"}'
```

So, I am basically checking I have seen `"Channel Statistics:"`, followed by `"Opacity:"` and then looking for `"Maximum:"` and then checking if the second column exceeds zero.

Hope that helps!